# concatenate recursive cross join

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, combinatorics, recursive-query

I need to concatenate the name in a recursive cross join way. I don't know how to do this, I have tried a CTE using `WITH RECURSIVE` but no success.

I have a table like this:

```
group_id | name
---------------
13       | A
13       | B
19       | C
19       | D
31       | E 
31       | F 
31       | G
```

Desired output:

```
combinations
------------
ACE
ACF
ACG
ADE
ADF
ADG
BCE
BCF
BCG
BDE
BDF
BDG
```

Of course, the results should multiply if I add a 4th (or more) group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Postgresql Syntax:

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0bcbc/2/0)**</kbd>

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS
(
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY group_id) AS rn
  FROM mytable
),cte2 AS
(
  SELECT 
    CAST(name AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS name,
    rn
  FROM cte1
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    CAST(CONCAT(c2.name,c1.name) AS VARCHAR(4000)) AS name
    ,c1.rn
  FROM cte1 c1
  JOIN cte2 c2
    ON c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
)
SELECT name as combinations
FROM cte2
WHERE LENGTH(name) = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM cte1)
ORDER BY name;
```

**Before:**

I hope if you don't mind that I use SQL Server Syntax:

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable(
   ID       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,TYPE     VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,TYPE) VALUES (13,'A');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,TYPE) VALUES (13,'B');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,TYPE) VALUES (19,'C');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,TYPE) VALUES (19,'D');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,TYPE) VALUES (31,'E');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,TYPE) VALUES (31,'F');
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,TYPE) VALUES (31,'G');
```

Main query:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
  FROM #mytable
),cte2 AS
(
  SELECT 
    TYPE = CAST(TYPE AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    rn
  FROM cte1
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    [Type]      = CAST(CONCAT(c2.TYPE,c1.TYPE) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    ,c1.rn
  FROM cte1 c1
  JOIN cte2 c2
    ON c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE LEN(Type) = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM cte1)
ORDER BY Type;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/378694)**</kbd>

I've assumed that the order of "cross join" is dependent on ascending ID.

- cte1 generate `DENSE_RANK()` because your IDs contain gaps
- cte2 recursive part with `CONCAT`
- main query just filter out required length and sort string

Comment: Awesome!! This does the trick. Your assumption about the order is correct for this example ;-) in reality I have added a display sequence column ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The **recursive query** is a bit simpler in Postgres:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (  -- to produce gapless group numbers
   SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY group_id) AS grp, name
   FROM   tbl
   )
, cte AS (
   SELECT grp, name
   FROM   t
   WHERE  grp = 1

   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.grp, c.name || t.name
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   t ON t.grp = c.grp + 1
   )
SELECT name AS combi
FROM   cte
WHERE  grp = (SELECT max(grp) FROM t)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The basic logic is the same as in the [SQL Server version provided by @lad2025](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33268107/939860), I added a couple of minor improvements.

**Or** you can use a **simple version** if your maximum number of groups is not too big (***can't be*** very big, really, since the result set grows exponentially). For a maximum of 5 groups:

```
WITH t AS (  -- to produce gapless group numbers
   SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY group_id) AS grp, name AS n
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT concat(t1.n, t2.n, t3.n, t4.n, t5.n) AS combi
FROM        (SELECT n FROM t WHERE grp = 1) t1
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT n FROM t WHERE grp = 2) t2 ON true
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT n FROM t WHERE grp = 3) t3 ON true
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT n FROM t WHERE grp = 4) t4 ON true
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT n FROM t WHERE grp = 5) t5 ON true
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Probably faster for few groups. `LEFT JOIN .. ON true` makes this work even if higher levels are missing. `concat()` ignores NULL values. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to be sure.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9affb/2) showing both.

Comment: Thanks. I need the recursive query for my goal. Your recursive version is indeed a bit cleaner. I think I will use that in my view.